# Plotly: How to extend the colorscheme of a plotly express scatterplot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

This is my code. But some colors are recycled. I need 52 different kinds of color. How can I solve this problem?

```
fig = px.scatter(Xt[:,0], Xt[:,1], color=DF["ScientifName"])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a function to create arbitrary color types. The desired graph will be created by setting the created color list to color. See this for [details](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.colors.html).

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.colors import n_colors
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0,53,52)
y = np.random.randint(0,53,52)

red_blue = n_colors('rgb(0, 0, 255)', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)', 52, colortype = 'rgb')

fig = px.scatter(x, y, color=red_blue)
fig.show()
```

[image]